# Following tests fails while trying to build QGIS from source

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, compilation

I have been trying to compile QGIS for a long time now.

---

What I did is:

1. Download Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 SDK, cygwin, osgeow4 (I followed [the instruction](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL) lines 380 - 447)
2. Additionally I have downloaded these packages using OSGeo4W:

   - qca-libs
   - qca-devel
   - python-devel
   - oci-devel
   - osgearth-dev
3. I have downloaded QGIS source branch *release-2_14*.
4. Using `ms-windows/osgeo4w/package.cmd` like this in command line

   ```
   cd C:\QtProjekty\QGIS-release-2_14\ms-windows\osgeo4w
   package.cmd 2.14.0 38 qgis-dev x86_64 >> log.txt
   ```

   I have managed to build source (I can see `qgis.exe` now in `ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-x86_64/output/bin/Release`)

---

Now I have found following lines in the log:

```
Test project C:/QtProjekty/QGIS-release-2_14/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-x86_64
          Start   1: ProcessingParametersTest
    1/195 Test   #1: ProcessingParametersTest ................***Failed    5.24 sec
          Start   2: ProcessingQgisAlgorithmsTest
    2/195 Test   #2: ProcessingQgisAlgorithmsTest ............***Failed    1.37 sec
          Start   3: ProcessingGdalAlgorithmsTest
    3/195 Test   #3: ProcessingGdalAlgorithmsTest ............***Failed    0.41 sec
          Start   4: qgis_applicationtest
    4/195 Test   #4: qgis_applicationtest ....................   Passed    6.90 sec
          Start   5: qgis_atlascompositiontest
    5/195 Test   #5: qgis_atlascompositiontest ...............   Passed    6.46 sec
          Start   6: qgis_authcryptotest
    6/195 Test   #6: qgis_authcryptotest .....................   Passed    1.08 sec
          Start   7: qgis_authconfigtest
    7/195 Test   #7: qgis_authconfigtest .....................   Passed    1.31 sec
          Start   8: qgis_authmanagertest
    8/195 Test   #8: qgis_authmanagertest ....................   Passed    6.63 sec
          Start   9: qgis_blendmodestest
    9/195 Test   #9: qgis_blendmodestest .....................   Passed    2.13 sec
          Start  10: qgis_clippertest
   10/195 Test  #10: qgis_clippertest ........................   Passed    0.15 sec
          Start  11: qgis_colorschemetest
   11/195 Test  #11: qgis_colorschemetest ....................   Passed    0.04 sec
          Start  12: qgis_colorschemeregistry
   12/195 Test  #12: qgis_colorschemeregistry ................   Passed    0.16 sec
          Start  13: qgis_composerddtest
   13/195 Test  #13: qgis_composerddtest .....................   Passed    1.04 sec
          Start  14: qgis_composereffectstest
   14/195 Test  #14: qgis_composereffectstest ................   Passed    1.59 sec
          Start  15: qgis_composergrouptest
   15/195 Test  #15: qgis_composergrouptest ..................   Passed    1.17 sec
          Start  16: qgis_composerhtmltest
   16/195 Test  #16: qgis_composerhtmltest ...................   Passed    4.26 sec
          Start  17: qgis_composerlabeltest
   17/195 Test  #17: qgis_composerlabeltest ..................   Passed    1.07 sec
          Start  18: qgis_composermapgridtest
   18/195 Test  #18: qgis_composermapgridtest ................   Passed    5.31 sec
          Start  19: qgis_composermapoverviewtest
   19/195 Test  #19: qgis_composermapoverviewtest ............   Passed    1.95 sec
          Start  20: qgis_composermaptest
   20/195 Test  #20: qgis_composermaptest ....................   Passed    2.50 sec
          Start  21: qgis_composermodel
   21/195 Test  #21: qgis_composermodel ......................   Passed    1.01 sec
          Start  22: qgis_composermultiframetest
   22/195 Test  #22: qgis_composermultiframetest .............   Passed    1.42 sec
          Start  23: qgis_composerobject
   23/195 Test  #23: qgis_composerobject .....................   Passed    1.03 sec
          Start  24: qgis_composerpapertest
   24/195 Test  #24: qgis_composerpapertest ..................   Passed    1.73 sec
          Start  25: qgis_composerpicturetest
   25/195 Test  #25: qgis_composerpicturetest ................   Passed    3.38 sec
          Start  26: qgis_composerrotationtest
   26/195 Test  #26: qgis_composerrotationtest ...............   Passed    1.85 sec
          Start  27: qgis_composerscalebartest
   27/195 Test  #27: qgis_composerscalebartest ...............   Passed    2.64 sec
          Start  28: qgis_composershapestest
   28/195 Test  #28: qgis_composershapestest .................   Passed    1.81 sec
          Start  29: qgis_composertabletest
   29/195 Test  #29: qgis_composertabletest ..................   Passed    1.20 sec
          Start  30: qgis_composertablev2test
   30/195 Test  #30: qgis_composertablev2test ................   Passed    3.06 sec
          Start  31: qgis_composerutils
   31/195 Test  #31: qgis_composerutils ......................   Passed    1.25 sec
          Start  32: qgis_compositiontest
   32/195 Test  #32: qgis_compositiontest ....................   Passed    1.56 sec
          Start  33: qgis_contrastenhancementtest
   33/195 Test  #33: qgis_contrastenhancementtest ............   Passed    0.03 sec
          Start  34: qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest
   34/195 Test  #34: qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest ......***Failed    1.29 sec
          Start  35: qgis_coordinatetransformtest
   35/195 Test  #35: qgis_coordinatetransformtest ............   Passed    1.10 sec
          Start  36: qgis_datadefined
   36/195 Test  #36: qgis_datadefined ........................   Passed    1.08 sec
          Start  37: qgis_dataitemtest
   37/195 Test  #37: qgis_dataitemtest .......................   Passed    2.51 sec
          Start  38: qgis_datasourceuritest
   38/195 Test  #38: qgis_datasourceuritest ..................   Passed    0.15 sec
          Start  39: qgis_diagramtest
   39/195 Test  #39: qgis_diagramtest ........................   Passed    2.10 sec
          Start  40: qgis_distanceareatest
   40/195 Test  #40: qgis_distanceareatest ...................   Passed    1.31 sec
          Start  41: qgis_ellipsemarkertest
   41/195 Test  #41: qgis_ellipsemarkertest ..................   Passed    1.29 sec
          Start  42: qgis_expressioncontext
   42/195 Test  #42: qgis_expressioncontext ..................   Passed    1.11 sec
          Start  43: qgis_expressiontest
   43/195 Test  #43: qgis_expressiontest .....................   Passed    2.25 sec
          Start  44: qgis_featuretest
   44/195 Test  #44: qgis_featuretest ........................   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  45: qgis_fieldstest
   45/195 Test  #45: qgis_fieldstest .........................   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  46: qgis_fieldtest
   46/195 Test  #46: qgis_fieldtest ..........................   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  47: qgis_filewritertest
   47/195 Test  #47: qgis_filewritertest .....................   Passed    0.81 sec
          Start  48: qgis_fontmarkertest2
   48/195 Test  #48: qgis_fontmarkertest2 ....................   Passed    1.33 sec
          Start  49: qgis_geometryimporttest
   49/195 Test  #49: qgis_geometryimporttest .................   Passed    0.12 sec
          Start  50: qgis_geometrytest
   50/195 Test  #50: qgis_geometrytest .......................   Passed    1.54 sec
          Start  51: qgis_geometryutilstest
   51/195 Test  #51: qgis_geometryutilstest ..................   Passed    0.03 sec
          Start  52: qgis_gradienttest
   52/195 Test  #52: qgis_gradienttest .......................   Passed    1.86 sec
          Start  53: qgis_graduatedsymbolrenderertest
   53/195 Test  #53: qgis_graduatedsymbolrenderertest ........   Passed    0.03 sec
          Start  54: qgis_histogramtest
   54/195 Test  #54: qgis_histogramtest ......................   Passed    1.22 sec
          Start  55: qgis_imageoperationtest
   55/195 Test  #55: qgis_imageoperationtest .................   Passed    4.52 sec
          Start  56: qgis_invertedpolygontest
   56/195 Test  #56: qgis_invertedpolygontest ................   Passed    1.93 sec
          Start  57: qgis_labelingenginev2
   57/195 Test  #57: qgis_labelingenginev2 ...................   Passed    2.09 sec
          Start  58: qgis_layertree
   58/195 Test  #58: qgis_layertree ..........................   Passed    1.16 sec
          Start  59: qgis_legendrenderertest
   59/195 Test  #59: qgis_legendrenderertest .................***Failed    1.60 sec
          Start  60: qgis_linefillsymboltest
   60/195 Test  #60: qgis_linefillsymboltest .................   Passed    1.30 sec
          Start  61: qgis_maplayerstylemanager
   61/195 Test  #61: qgis_maplayerstylemanager ...............   Passed    1.17 sec
          Start  62: qgis_maplayertest
   62/195 Test  #62: qgis_maplayertest .......................   Passed    1.09 sec
          Start  63: qgis_maprenderertest
   63/195 Test  #63: qgis_maprenderertest ....................   Passed    8.16 sec
          Start  64: qgis_maprotationtest
   64/195 Test  #64: qgis_maprotationtest ....................   Passed    1.25 sec
          Start  65: qgis_mapsettingstest
   65/195 Test  #65: qgis_mapsettingstest ....................   Passed    1.00 sec
          Start  66: qgis_maptopixelgeometrysimplifiertest
   66/195 Test  #66: qgis_maptopixelgeometrysimplifiertest ...   Passed    1.11 sec
          Start  67: qgis_maptopixeltest
   67/195 Test  #67: qgis_maptopixeltest .....................   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  68: qgis_markerlinessymboltest
   68/195 Test  #68: qgis_markerlinessymboltest ..............   Passed    1.38 sec
          Start  69: qgis_networkcontentfetcher
   69/195 Test  #69: qgis_networkcontentfetcher ..............   Passed    3.55 sec
          Start  70: qgis_ogcutilstest
   70/195 Test  #70: qgis_ogcutilstest .......................   Passed    1.00 sec
          Start  71: qgis_painteffectregistrytest
   71/195 Test  #71: qgis_painteffectregistrytest ............   Passed    0.03 sec
          Start  72: qgis_painteffecttest
   72/195 Test  #72: qgis_painteffecttest ....................   Passed    1.92 sec
          Start  73: qgis_pallabelingtest
   73/195 Test  #73: qgis_pallabelingtest ....................   Passed    0.04 sec
          Start  74: qgis_pointlocatortest
   74/195 Test  #74: qgis_pointlocatortest ...................   Passed    1.51 sec
          Start  75: qgis_pointpatternfillsymboltest
   75/195 Test  #75: qgis_pointpatternfillsymboltest .........   Passed    1.22 sec
          Start  76: qgis_pointtest
   76/195 Test  #76: qgis_pointtest ..........................   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  77: qgis_projecttest
   77/195 Test  #77: qgis_projecttest ........................   Passed    0.15 sec
          Start  78: qgis_qgistest
   78/195 Test  #78: qgis_qgistest ...........................   Passed    0.09 sec
          Start  79: qgis_rasterfilewritertest
   79/195 Test  #79: qgis_rasterfilewritertest ...............   Passed   13.84 sec
          Start  80: qgis_rasterfilltest
   80/195 Test  #80: qgis_rasterfilltest .....................   Passed    1.62 sec
          Start  81: qgis_rasterlayertest
   81/195 Test  #81: qgis_rasterlayertest ....................***Failed    2.32 sec
          Start  82: qgis_rastersublayertest
   82/195 Test  #82: qgis_rastersublayertest .................   Passed    1.18 sec
          Start  83: qgis_rectangletest
   83/195 Test  #83: qgis_rectangletest ......................   Passed    0.13 sec
          Start  84: qgis_regression1141
   84/195 Test  #84: qgis_regression1141 .....................   Passed    1.26 sec
          Start  85: qgis_regression992
   85/195 Test  #85: qgis_regression992 ......................   Passed    1.41 sec
          Start  86: qgis_rendererstest
   86/195 Test  #86: qgis_rendererstest ......................   Passed    1.60 sec
          Start  87: qgis_rulebasedrenderertest
   87/195 Test  #87: qgis_rulebasedrenderertest ..............   Passed    1.06 sec
          Start  88: qgis_scaleexpressiontest
   88/195 Test  #88: qgis_scaleexpressiontest ................   Passed    1.08 sec
          Start  89: qgis_shapebursttest
   89/195 Test  #89: qgis_shapebursttest .....................   Passed    2.23 sec
          Start  90: qgis_simplemarkertest
   90/195 Test  #90: qgis_simplemarkertest ...................   Passed    1.41 sec
          Start  91: qgis_snappingutilstest
   91/195 Test  #91: qgis_snappingutilstest ..................   Passed    1.65 sec
          Start  92: qgis_spatialindextest
   92/195 Test  #92: qgis_spatialindextest ...................   Passed    3.82 sec
          Start  93: qgis_statisticalsummarytest
   93/195 Test  #93: qgis_statisticalsummarytest .............   Passed    0.14 sec
          Start  94: qgis_stringutilstest
   94/195 Test  #94: qgis_stringutilstest ....................   Passed    0.05 sec
          Start  95: qgis_stylev2test
   95/195 Test  #95: qgis_stylev2test ........................   Passed    5.64 sec
          Start  96: qgis_svgmarkertest
   96/195 Test  #96: qgis_svgmarkertest ......................   Passed    1.31 sec
          Start  97: qgis_symbolv2test
   97/195 Test  #97: qgis_symbolv2test .......................   Passed    1.98 sec
          Start  98: qgis_tracertest
   98/195 Test  #98: qgis_tracertest .........................   Passed    1.14 sec
          Start  99: qgis_typographicstylingutils
   99/195 Test  #99: qgis_typographicstylingutils ............   Passed    1.01 sec
          Start 100: qgis_vectordataprovidertest
  100/195 Test #100: qgis_vectordataprovidertest .............   Passed    1.18 sec
          Start 101: qgis_vectorlayercachetest
  101/195 Test #101: qgis_vectorlayercachetest ...............   Passed    1.10 sec
          Start 102: qgis_vectorlayerjoinbuffer
  102/195 Test #102: qgis_vectorlayerjoinbuffer ..............   Passed    1.26 sec
          Start 103: qgis_vectorlayertest
  103/195 Test #103: qgis_vectorlayertest ....................   Passed    1.19 sec
          Start 104: qgis_ziplayertest
  104/195 Test #104: qgis_ziplayertest .......................   Passed    5.05 sec
          Start 105: qgis_zoomtest
  105/195 Test #105: qgis_zoomtest ...........................   Passed    1.33 sec
          Start 106: qgis_doublespinbox
  106/195 Test #106: qgis_doublespinbox ......................   Passed    0.47 sec
          Start 107: qgis_dualviewtest
  107/195 Test #107: qgis_dualviewtest .......................   Passed    1.42 sec
          Start 108: qgis_fieldexpressionwidget
  108/195 Test #108: qgis_fieldexpressionwidget ..............   Passed    1.10 sec
          Start 109: qgis_filewidget
  109/195 Test #109: qgis_filewidget .........................   Passed    0.13 sec
          Start 110: qgis_mapcanvastest
  110/195 Test #110: qgis_mapcanvastest ......................   Passed    0.19 sec
          Start 111: qgis_projectionissues
  111/195 Test #111: qgis_projectionissues ...................   Passed    1.19 sec
          Start 112: qgis_qgsguitest
  112/195 Test #112: qgis_qgsguitest .........................   Passed    0.03 sec
          Start 113: qgis_rubberbandtest
  113/195 Test #113: qgis_rubberbandtest .....................   Passed    1.32 sec
          Start 114: qgis_scalecombobox
  114/195 Test #114: qgis_scalecombobox ......................   Passed    1.17 sec
          Start 115: qgis_spinbox
  115/195 Test #115: qgis_spinbox ............................   Passed    0.16 sec
          Start 116: qgis_analyzertest
  116/195 Test #116: qgis_analyzertest .......................   Passed    1.54 sec
          Start 117: qgis_openstreetmaptest
  117/195 Test #117: qgis_openstreetmaptest ..................   Passed   15.21 sec
          Start 118: qgis_zonalstatisticstest
  118/195 Test #118: qgis_zonalstatisticstest ................   Passed    1.20 sec
          Start 119: qgis_rastercalculatortest
  119/195 Test #119: qgis_rastercalculatortest ...............   Passed    1.35 sec
          Start 120: qgis_alignrastertest
  120/195 Test #120: qgis_alignrastertest ....................***Failed    0.63 sec
          Start 121: qgis_wcsprovidertest
  121/195 Test #121: qgis_wcsprovidertest ....................   Passed   13.29 sec
          Start 122: qgis_gdalprovidertest
  122/195 Test #122: qgis_gdalprovidertest ...................   Passed    1.25 sec
          Start 123: qgis_grassprovidertest7
  123/195 Test #123: qgis_grassprovidertest7 .................   Passed   54.96 sec
          Start 124: qgis_qgisappclipboard
  124/195 Test #124: qgis_qgisappclipboard ...................   Passed    2.06 sec
          Start 125: qgis_attributetabletest
  125/195 Test #125: qgis_attributetabletest .................   Passed    1.63 sec
          Start 126: qgis_fieldcalculatortest
  126/195 Test #126: qgis_fieldcalculatortest ................   Passed    3.13 sec
          Start 127: qgis_maptoolidentifyaction
  127/195 Test #127: qgis_maptoolidentifyaction ..............   Passed    1.58 sec
          Start 128: qgis_measuretool
  128/195 Test #128: qgis_measuretool ........................   Passed    1.48 sec
          Start 129: PyQgsLocalServer
  129/195 Test #129: PyQgsLocalServer ........................   Passed    0.59 sec
          Start 130: PyQgsAnalysis
  130/195 Test #130: PyQgsAnalysis ...........................   Passed   12.73 sec
          Start 131: PyQgsApplication
  131/195 Test #131: PyQgsApplication ........................   Passed    2.69 sec
          Start 132: PyQgsAtlasComposition
  132/195 Test #132: PyQgsAtlasComposition ...................   Passed    5.71 sec
          Start 133: PyQgsAttributeTableModel
  133/195 Test #133: PyQgsAttributeTableModel ................   Passed    2.60 sec
          Start 134: PyQgsBlendModes
  134/195 Test #134: PyQgsBlendModes .........................***Failed    0.32 sec
          Start 135: PyQgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2
  135/195 Test #135: PyQgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2 ........   Passed    2.50 sec
          Start 136: PyQgsColorScheme
  136/195 Test #136: PyQgsColorScheme ........................   Passed    0.34 sec
          Start 137: PyQgsColorSchemeRegistry
  137/195 Test #137: PyQgsColorSchemeRegistry ................   Passed    0.21 sec
          Start 138: PyQgsComposerEffects
  138/195 Test #138: PyQgsComposerEffects ....................   Passed    2.76 sec
          Start 139: PyQgsComposerHtml
  139/195 Test #139: PyQgsComposerHtml .......................***Failed    0.28 sec
          Start 140: PyQgsComposerLabel
  140/195 Test #140: PyQgsComposerLabel ......................   Passed    2.57 sec
          Start 141: PyQgsComposerMap
  141/195 Test #141: PyQgsComposerMap ........................   Passed    3.32 sec
          Start 142: PyQgsComposerMapGrid
  142/195 Test #142: PyQgsComposerMapGrid ....................   Passed    3.65 sec
          Start 143: PyQgsComposerPicture
  143/195 Test #143: PyQgsComposerPicture ....................   Passed    4.87 sec
          Start 144: PyQgsComposerShapes
  144/195 Test #144: PyQgsComposerShapes .....................   Passed    3.06 sec
          Start 145: PyQgsComposition
  145/195 Test #145: PyQgsComposition ........................***Failed    0.28 sec
          Start 146: PyQgsConditionalStyle
  146/195 Test #146: PyQgsConditionalStyle ...................   Passed    2.51 sec
          Start 147: PyQgsCoordinateTransform
  147/195 Test #147: PyQgsCoordinateTransform ................   Passed    2.49 sec
          Start 148: PyQgsDelimitedTextProvider
  148/195 Test #148: PyQgsDelimitedTextProvider ..............   Passed    7.61 sec
          Start 149: PyQgsDistanceArea
  149/195 Test #149: PyQgsDistanceArea .......................   Passed    2.56 sec
          Start 150: PyQgsEditWidgets
  150/195 Test #150: PyQgsEditWidgets ........................   Passed    2.85 sec
          Start 151: PyQgsExpression
  151/195 Test #151: PyQgsExpression .........................   Passed    0.34 sec
          Start 152: PyQgsFeature
  152/195 Test #152: PyQgsFeature ............................   Passed    2.53 sec
          Start 153: PyQgsProject
  153/195 Test #153: PyQgsProject ............................   Passed    3.81 sec
          Start 154: PyQgsFeatureIterator
  154/195 Test #154: PyQgsFeatureIterator ....................   Passed    2.59 sec
          Start 155: PyQgsField
  155/195 Test #155: PyQgsField ..............................   Passed    2.60 sec
          Start 156: PyQgsFontUtils
  156/195 Test #156: PyQgsFontUtils ..........................   Passed    2.55 sec
          Start 157: PyQgsGeometryAvoidIntersections
  157/195 Test #157: PyQgsGeometryAvoidIntersections .........   Passed    2.49 sec
          Start 158: PyQgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayerV2
  158/195 Test #158: PyQgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayerV2 .....***Failed    0.26 sec
          Start 159: PyQgsGeometryTest
  159/195 Test #159: PyQgsGeometryTest .......................   Passed    3.06 sec
          Start 160: PyQgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2
  160/195 Test #160: PyQgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2 ..........   Passed    2.54 sec
          Start 161: PyQgsMapUnitScale
  161/195 Test #161: PyQgsMapUnitScale .......................   Passed    0.31 sec
          Start 162: PyQgsMemoryProvider
  162/195 Test #162: PyQgsMemoryProvider .....................   Passed    2.63 sec
          Start 163: PyQgsNetworkContentFetcher
  163/195 Test #163: PyQgsNetworkContentFetcher ..............   Passed    7.89 sec
          Start 164: PyQgsPalLabelingBase
  164/195 Test #164: PyQgsPalLabelingBase ....................***Failed    0.27 sec
          Start 165: PyQgsPalLabelingCanvas
  165/195 Test #165: PyQgsPalLabelingCanvas ..................***Failed    0.32 sec
          Start 166: PyQgsPalLabelingComposer
  166/195 Test #166: PyQgsPalLabelingComposer ................***Failed    0.35 sec
          Start 167: PyQgsPalLabelingPlacement
  167/195 Test #167: PyQgsPalLabelingPlacement ...............***Failed    0.28 sec
          Start 168: PyQgsPoint
  168/195 Test #168: PyQgsPoint ..............................   Passed    2.43 sec
          Start 169: PyQgsRangeWidgets
  169/195 Test #169: PyQgsRangeWidgets .......................   Passed    2.64 sec
          Start 170: PyQgsRasterFileWriter
  170/195 Test #170: PyQgsRasterFileWriter ...................   Passed    3.34 sec
          Start 171: PyQgsRasterLayer
  171/195 Test #171: PyQgsRasterLayer ........................   Passed    2.69 sec
          Start 172: PyQgsRectangle
  172/195 Test #172: PyQgsRectangle ..........................   Passed    2.56 sec
          Start 173: PyQgsRelation
  173/195 Test #173: PyQgsRelation ...........................   Passed    2.53 sec
          Start 174: PyQgsRulebasedRenderer
  174/195 Test #174: PyQgsRulebasedRenderer ..................***Failed    0.27 sec
          Start 175: PyQgsSingleSymbolRenderer
  175/195 Test #175: PyQgsSingleSymbolRenderer ...............***Failed    0.22 sec
          Start 176: PyQgsShapefileProvider
  176/195 Test #176: PyQgsShapefileProvider ..................   Passed    2.79 sec
          Start 177: PyQgsTabfileProvider
  177/195 Test #177: PyQgsTabfileProvider ....................   Passed    2.66 sec
          Start 178: PyQgsSpatialIndex
  178/195 Test #178: PyQgsSpatialIndex .......................   Passed    2.46 sec
          Start 179: PyQgsSpatialiteProvider
  179/195 Test #179: PyQgsSpatialiteProvider .................***Failed    0.36 sec
          Start 180: PyQgsSymbolLayerV2
  180/195 Test #180: PyQgsSymbolLayerV2 ......................   Passed    2.62 sec
          Start 181: PyQgsSymbolExpressionVariables
  181/195 Test #181: PyQgsSymbolExpressionVariables ..........***Failed    0.29 sec
          Start 182: PyQgsSyntacticSugar
  182/195 Test #182: PyQgsSyntacticSugar .....................   Passed    2.45 sec
          Start 183: PyQgsSymbolV2
  183/195 Test #183: PyQgsSymbolV2 ...........................   Passed    3.15 sec
          Start 184: PyQgsUnitTypes
  184/195 Test #184: PyQgsUnitTypes ..........................   Passed    0.27 sec
          Start 185: PyQgsVectorColorRamp
  185/195 Test #185: PyQgsVectorColorRamp ....................   Passed    1.35 sec
          Start 186: PyQgsVectorFileWriter
  186/195 Test #186: PyQgsVectorFileWriter ...................   Passed    3.03 sec
          Start 187: PyQgsVectorLayer
  187/195 Test #187: PyQgsVectorLayer ........................   Passed    2.89 sec
          Start 188: PyQgsZonalStatistics
  188/195 Test #188: PyQgsZonalStatistics ....................   Passed    2.60 sec
          Start 189: PyQgsMapLayerRegistry
  189/195 Test #189: PyQgsMapLayerRegistry ...................   Passed    0.25 sec
          Start 190: PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider
  190/195 Test #190: PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider ...............***Failed    0.30 sec
          Start 191: PyQgsVirtualLayerDefinition
  191/195 Test #191: PyQgsVirtualLayerDefinition .............***Failed    0.24 sec
          Start 192: PyQgsLayerDefinition
  192/195 Test #192: PyQgsLayerDefinition ....................   Passed    2.56 sec
          Start 193: PyQgsAppStartup
  193/195 Test #193: PyQgsAppStartup .........................   Passed   21.66 sec
          Start 194: PyQgsServer
  194/195 Test #194: PyQgsServer .............................***Failed    3.40 sec
          Start 195: PyQgsServerAccessControl
  195/195 Test #195: PyQgsServerAccessControl ................   Passed    8.62 sec

  89% tests passed, 22 tests failed out of 195

  Total Test time (real) = 486.90 sec

  The following tests FAILED:
      1 - ProcessingParametersTest (Failed)
      2 - ProcessingQgisAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
      3 - ProcessingGdalAlgorithmsTest (Failed)
     34 - qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest (Failed)
     59 - qgis_legendrenderertest (Failed)
     81 - qgis_rasterlayertest (Failed)
    120 - qgis_alignrastertest (Failed)
    134 - PyQgsBlendModes (Failed)
    139 - PyQgsComposerHtml (Failed)
    145 - PyQgsComposition (Failed)
    158 - PyQgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayerV2 (Failed)
    164 - PyQgsPalLabelingBase (Failed)
    165 - PyQgsPalLabelingCanvas (Failed)
    166 - PyQgsPalLabelingComposer (Failed)
    167 - PyQgsPalLabelingPlacement (Failed)
    174 - PyQgsRulebasedRenderer (Failed)
    175 - PyQgsSingleSymbolRenderer (Failed)
    179 - PyQgsSpatialiteProvider (Failed)
    181 - PyQgsSymbolExpressionVariables (Failed)
    190 - PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider (Failed)
    191 - PyQgsVirtualLayerDefinition (Failed)
    194 - PyQgsServer (Failed)
```

---

My questions now are:

- What are the logs above?
- Are those tests needed to pass in order to have successfull build or is my `qgis.exe` working properly already?
- Why are there no information in the instruction about additional packages needed to build the source?
- Are there any other packages required to have successful build?

---

After downloading packages:

- grass6
- qgis-devel

I have following output:

```
  The following tests FAILED:
     34 - qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest (Failed)
     59 - qgis_legendrenderertest (Failed)
     81 - qgis_rasterlayertest (Failed)
    120 - qgis_alignrastertest (Failed)
    167 - PyQgsPalLabelingComposer (Failed)
    191 - PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider (Failed)
    192 - PyQgsVirtualLayerDefinition (Failed)
    195 - PyQgsServer (Failed)
```

---

## Bounty started

I am not happy to say it but I am not able to get sufficient info about how to compile QGIS. It already took me too much time trying to compile it. Still I do not know what am I doing right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many tests haven't been fixed to work correctly under windows yet. You can safely ignore these failing tests as they aren't indicative of a problem with your build, and they fail even with the official windows builds (See eg http://dash.orfeo-toolbox.org/viewTest.php?onlyfailed&buildid=222811 ).

The qgis_alignrastertest test fails because it needs to be updated to handle differences in GDAL >= 2.0. This test covers the "align rasters" tool available under the raster menu. It's failing because GDAL 2.0 changed how various resampling algorithms are calculated.

The following tests have been fixed in master and should pass if you update your QGIS to the latest git version:

- qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest
- qgis_rasterlayertest
- PyQgsVirtualLayerDefinition
- qgis_legendrenderertest

The PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider test currently fails on ALL Windows builds. It's due to invalid handling of accented characters under Windows when using virtual query layers. Even the official builds of QGIS suffer this issue - it just hasn't been resolved yet on Windows.

The PyQgsServer test should pass. You may be missing a dependency. Try running the test in verbose mode, ie `ctest -v -r PyQgsServer` and see if there's any clues there.

Lastly, PyQgsPalLabelingComposer requires some command line PDF tools available in your path. You need to install poppler and add it's directory to your path. Again, some pointers are given when running the test in verbose mode.

Comment: Thank you. Can you link a source of these information? Also I still need answer to "what are these tests?" and "what does it mean they fail? Will the program work properly? What will not work if 8 tests fail, what if 22 does (like in logs I provided)?"

Comment: I've just updated the answer to add some more detail, and to cover changes in the QGIS master code in the last 24 hours

Comment: Thank you for the update. I still need to know what happens if a test fails. Does this mean that certain part of the program will not work?

Comment: It's a mix. For most of these it's just the test itself which is broken (eg PyQgsServer, qgis_alignrastertest and PyQgsPalLabelingComposer) which mean that QGIS will work, it's just the test which doesn't. But PyQgsVirtualLayerProvider is revealing a bug in QGIS itself on Windows - however, even the official builds have this bug, it's not an issue specific to your build.

Comment: Oh, you also asked about my source - see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/graphs/contributors. I've written a lot of the QGIS testing code and know it backwards.